# (Python) Discord bot code returns "RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop"

Tags: python, runtime-error, discord.py, python-asyncio, spyder

I was trying to create code in Spyder to start my discord bot, but I encountered the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
runfile('C:/Users/Nathan/Desktop/HW/Python stuff/my_discord_bot.py', wdir='C:/Users/Nathan/Desktop/HW/Python stuff')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Nathan/Desktop/HW/Python stuff/my_discord_bot.py", line 17, in 
client.run('my application token')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 705, in run
_cleanup_loop(loop)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 98, in _cleanup_loop
loop.close()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 83, in close
raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")

RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop

I've searched online and someone told me to use a package called "nest_asyncio". I pip installed the package, imported it, and ran nest_asyncio.apply() in the console, but the code still gave the same error after running it again.

This was my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ('Bot is ready.')
    
client.run('my application token')
```

By the way, I replaced my actual token with "my application token" because I don't want to share it with anyone.

Please help. How do I get rid of this error and get it to run like normal?

Answer (score 6):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) In order to run async code in Spyder, you need to install a package called [nest-asyncio](https://pypi.org/project/nest-asyncio/) and add these two lines to be the first ones in your code:

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

Comment: I did that, but for some reason my code gave the same error.

Comment: If we are trying to run in any other command prompt or any other framework like django or flask or any other environment like anaconda or jupiter, this might be the solution.

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking for this for days!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Instead of using Spyder's built-in console I used the command prompt to run my code, and this bypassed the RuntimeError.