# Installed aiohttps and nest_asyncio in Spyder (Anaconda 3), but still get Runtime Error

Tags: python, anaconda, discord.py, runtime-error, spyder

I'm trying to run a discord bot in Spyder (anaconda 3 version), but it keeps giving me the `Runtime error`, similar to the one in these two questions:

- [Cannot close a running event loop. Discord bot creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308995/cannot-close-a-running-event-loop-discord-bot-creation)
- [(Python) Discord bot code returns "RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297553/python-discord-bot-code-returns-runtimeerror-cannot-close-a-running-event-lo)

I have installed `nest_asyncio` and `aiohttps`
As for installing Discord.py Rewrite, I'm not 100% sure whether I have it or not. In conda, I installed discord.py by typing `conda install -c conda-forge discord.py` I am using Windows 10.

In the second question, they said they tried running their code in the command prompt, so I tried that and got this:

```
  client.run(TOKEN)
File "C:\Users\swanl\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
  return future.result()
File "C:\Users\swanl\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 178, in result
  raise self._exception
File "C:\Users\swanl\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 280, in __step
  result = coro.send(None)
File "C:\Users\swanl\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
  await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\swanl\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
  await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
File "C:\Users\swanl\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
  await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Here's my code:

```
import os
import discord

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `os.getenv` returns `None` if the key doesn't exist, have you made sure `TOKEN` was your actual token and not a NoneType?

Comment: Thanks, I figured out a way here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65685817/16411361
I ran my environment variable code in startup.